# OBD 2 Fuel reading says No Data

Tags: obd-ii

I wanted to read fuel level from the car and display it on my application.

The communication was established using the ELM327 Bluetooth interface dongle.

The ELM module replies `NO DATA` for the code `012F\r`.

Is there any other way to calculate or get fuel level using OBD.

Comment: It really depends on the vehicle and whether the information is passed through the CAN Bus. If it's just a regular sensor which passes an electric signal directly to the fuel gauge, you aren't going to have the information available. Some vehicles will do it this way while others won't. It all depends on the manufacturer.

Comment: you mean to say that there is no other way to calculate fuel level???

Comment: If it doesn't communicate through the CAN Bus, you won't be able to get it through the DLC port. You'll have to research if your vehicle does/doesn't transmit this info through the port. If the vehicle has an onboard mileage calculator, it should communicate it that way. If so and you are getting the above message, you may be sending the wrong code. I personally don't know what that code would be ... haven't delved that deep into the CAN Bus system (though I should, lol).

Comment: What is the make, model and year of the vehicle?

Comment: @NateEldredge it is a Maruti-Suzuki Alto (India, petrol car). I don't know the exact year of vehicle.

Comment: I want to know is there a way to know fuel reading from car using OBD other than the command "012f" ?? I mean any calculations

Comment: You can find the model year by looking at the [VIN number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number#Model_year_encoding).

Comment: Car Make is 2009

Comment: I wonder if @ducatikiller would know about this? Not testing you bro, just thinking this would be up your alley.

Comment: I only have USDM cars to base this off, but fuel level is sent to the pcm. Unsure of the OBD2 command though.

Comment: Also what is the /r in the command? When looking at the ELM327 documentation the format shown would be 01 2F.

Answer (score 3):

The alto does not have the fuel reading on OBD instead you can calculate the consumption with the help of the MAF data.